# How to insert row at any desired position in datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a datatable which contains 10 rows. I now need to insert 11th row at the position specified by some conditions.

I have tried the InsertAt method but that gives the error of "this row already belongs to another table".

I cannot use ImportRow method as that simply import the rows into datatable and inserts the row at the end of the existing rows.

What should i do? Kindly help!

Thanks

**UPDATED CODE**

```
        int iCount = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtWithBundle.Rows)
        {
            DataRow drClone = dtOppClone.NewRow();
            drClone.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
            dtOpps.Rows.InsertAt(drClone, iIndex + iCount);
            //dtOpps.ImportRow(drClone);
            //dtOpps.Rows.Add(drClone.ItemArray); // Commented on Aug-4 2011 1700HRS
            iCount++;
            dtOpps.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Rows in DataTables don't have 'Positions' you can rely on. Define a SortOrder.

Comment: Position here is being referred to as the second argument(i.e Position) in InsertAt Method.

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: create clone of datable and insert record to clone `dt2.ImportRow(row)`

Comment: Doesn't matter, DataTable is position-agnostic until you give it a sort column. You'll need to define a hidden column called "priority", and use that to order the columns. When you insert a new row, update the priorities of the other rows and then insert it in the proper position.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this. I think the error you are getting is bcz you are not creating NewRow.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "A";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "C";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "B";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr,1);

    foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d[0].ToString());

    }

    Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

A DataTable is like an SQL table.  It doesn't really have the concept of physical positions.  You have to give the row a value that will sort the way you want it to when retrieving a set of rows.

[Edit]  The documentation is a bit nebulous:

The location specified by InsertAt is reflected by the order of rows in the DataRowCollection only. If more than one row is returned in a DataRow array, the **inserted row may not be returned in the location specified by InsertAt.**

For more info, check

[DataRowCollection.InsertAt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWCOLLECTION.INSERTAT%29%3Bk%28INSERTAT%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29%3Bk%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

Comment: Say ColumnA contains values like 'aa', 'bb', 'cc'....  If you want the new row to be at the end of the set when you sort by ColumnA, give ColumnA the value of 'zz'.

Answer (score 0):

The example below shows you how to insert multiple rows at different positions, where the positioning may change, thus row number count in the *DataTable*.

Note the use of r and rNo:

```
        'sum classifications in a budget
        Dim ClassID As Integer = 0
        Dim ClassTotal As Decimal = 0
        Dim GrandTotal As Decimal = 0
        Dim rNo As Integer = 0
        Dim rw As DataRow = Nothing
        Dim RowCount As Integer = dt.Rows.Count

        For r As Integer = 0 To RowCount - 1
            If ClassID <> dt.Rows(rNo)("ClassificationID") Then
                If rNo <> 0 Then
                    'add sub total
                    rw = dt.NewRow()
                    rw("Classification") = "Sub-Total"
                    rw("Amount") = ClassTotal
                    dt.Rows.InsertAt(rw, rNo)
                    'reset sub total
                    ClassTotal = 0
                    'increment row count because of inserted row
                    rNo += 1
                End If
                ClassID = dt.Rows(rNo)("ClassificationID")
            End If
            ClassTotal += dt.Rows(rNo)("Amount")
            GrandTotal += dt.Rows(rNo)("Amount")
            rNo += 1
        Next
        'add grand total
        rw = dt.NewRow
        rw("Classification") = "Sub-Total"
        rw("Amount") = ClassTotal
        dt.Rows.Add(rw)

        'add grand total
        rw = dt.NewRow
        rw("Classification") = "Grand Total"
        rw("Amount") = GrandTotal
        dt.Rows.Add(rw)
```

*Code in VB.net. Please convert to C# for your use