# Hide buttons for last row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using code below to hide/edit and delete he last row in a `gridview`.

When I use page indexing the buttons are getting hidden on the last row, in each page?

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[gvDetails.Rows.Count - 1];
    lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
    lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
 }
```

Any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Also I am using this below method to bind the grid and add a new datarow which has sum of columns. Now how can I add this datarow as the first row of the gridview.

```
public void LoadData()
{
    DataTable dtDetails = DetailsDataRepository.GetDetails();
    BindDetailsGrid(dtDetails);
    DataTable dt = DetailsDataRepository.GetSum();
    DataRow dr = dtDetails.NewRow();
    dr["Total_Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["Total_Amount"].ToString().Substring(1)).ToString("C0");
    dr["Monthly_Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["Monthly_Amount"].ToString().Substring(1)).ToString("C0");
    dtDetails.Rows.InsertAt(dr,0);
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtDetails;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
    if (gvDetails.PageIndex == 0)
    {
        var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[0];
        lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("lblComments").Visible = false;
        lastRow.Height = 35;
        lastRow.Font.Size = 11;
        lastRow.Font.Bold = true;
    }        
}
```

**Page Indexing:**

```
protected void gvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
    if (gvDetails.PageIndex == 0)
    {
        var lastRow = gvODetails.Rows[0];
        lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("lblComments").Visible = false;
        lastRow.Height = 35;
        lastRow.Font.Size = 11;
        lastRow.Font.Bold = true;
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

```
public void LoadData()
{
    DataTable dtDetails = DetailsDataRepository.GetDetails();
    BindDetailsGrid(dtDetails);
    DataTable dt = DetailsDataRepository.GetSum();
    DataRow dr = dtDetails.NewRow();
    dr["Total_Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["Total_Amount"].ToString().Substring(1)).ToString("C0");
    dr["Monthly_Amount"] = Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[0]["Monthly_Amount"].ToString().Substring(1)).ToString("C0");
    dtDetails.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    gvDetails.DataSource = dtDetails;
    gvDetails.DataBind();
    if (gvDetails.PageIndex == 0)
    {
        var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[0];
        lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
        lastRow.FindControl("lblComments").Visible = false;
        lastRow.Height = 35;
        lastRow.Font.Size = 11;
        lastRow.Font.Bold = true;
        lastRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    }  
}
```

**Page Indexing:**

```
protected void gvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
 gvDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
 BindGrid();
 if (gvDetails.PageIndex == 0)
  {
    var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[0];
    lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
    lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
    lastRow.FindControl("lblComments").Visible = false;
    lastRow.Height = 35;
    lastRow.Font.Size = 11;
    lastRow.Font.Bold = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: you check last row in different grids `gvOBMDetails.Rows[gvDetails.Rows.Count - 1]`

Comment: `gvDetails.Rows.Count` will give you current visible rows count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if(gvOBMDetails.PageCount == 1)//Updated
{
    var lastRow = gvOBMDetails.Rows[gvOBMDetails.Rows.Count - 1];
    lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
    lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
}
else if(gvOBMDetails.PageIndex == gvOBMDetails.PageCount -1)
{
    var lastRow = gvOBMDetails.Rows[gvOBMDetails.Rows.Count - 1];
    lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit").Visible = false;
    lastRow.FindControl("btnDelete").Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: This works fine. I have a gridview in someother page, where one of the column is a link button so when I click on any of the values it will navigate to this page. And now I can see the last row is highlighted and is there any solution to solve this?

Comment: @Vicky Add the above code immediately after binding the gridview or at page index changing event.

Comment: I have added the above code in Page_PreRender event. So click gridview column from someother page will land in this page.

Comment: Are you binding data in `Page_PreRender` event?

Comment: No in page load event.

Comment: I think, its better if you add it inside `PageIndexChanging` event. So that it will check for every page change.

Comment: If I'm using this in PageIndexChanging then how can I hide them for last row on pageload? The problem I need to have both working parallelly.

Comment: `gvOBMDetails.PageIndex` will give the current page index, `gvOBMDetails.PageCount` will give the total pages. So as per the code, if `PageIndex` is equal to `PageCount - 1` then that is the last page. So it will proceed to hide the buttons of last row of the last page.

Comment: This is perfect. But when I click on column values which has link button from someother page it will navigate here and show the last row with hidden buttons. I think I'm claer now.

Comment: After navigation, are you showing directly last page?

Comment: After I navigate from someother page to this page I m not showing the last page. The first page will be shown. For ex: The other page will be having a column named ID with the value 5 and if I click that 5 all the rows with that ID 5 will be displayed in this page.

Comment: Then add this code in two places, 1) in `PageIndexChanging` event and 2) in `Page_Load` after binding the gridview.

Comment: When I navigate from other page they are fine and it doesn't work on page load. I can see buttons are visible for last row.

Comment: As per code it should work if you add it in both places. Place a breakpoint in the `Page_Load` and check if it is going inside the `if` block.

Comment: yes but when it comes to the page if there is no page indexing in the page. For ex: I have set the pagesize to 50. But if the value has only 20 items then the last rows of the page will be taken correct? Also it goes into the if loop and doesn't go inside and check the statements.

Comment: Yes, in this case `PageIndex` will be 0 and `PageCount` will be 1, which satisfy the condition and will hide the buttons.

Comment: Is there any alternate for this?

Comment: Try the updated code in `Page_Load` after binding data to gridview.

Comment: I put this code after binding data in page load and doesn't work and works inside page_prerender

Comment: No it doesn't work thats the problem. In pageload this if conditions are not working:(In page_prerender it hides the buttons for last row after pageloads.

Comment: Are you sure you are placing the code after databind?(after `gvDetails.DataBind();`) If yes then place a breakpoint and check the `PageCount`. And try by altering the code accordingly, so that it will pass into the if condition and hide the last row buttons.

Comment: Then what is `PageCount`? Is it going inside the `if` block?

Comment: When I debug its not going inside if block. It goes to if line and when I press f10 again it goes to else if block.

Comment: So, the displayed page is not the last page. You need the buttons to be hidden which are at the last row of the last page right? If you go to the last page, then the buttons will be hidden.(If you have added the code in `PageIndexChanging` event).

Comment: I got that working and now how can I bring that datarow at the first row of the gridview and set the validation for first row like how we did similarly for last row?

Comment: For first row of the first page? For first page `PageIndex == 0` and for first row `gvOBMDetails.Rows[0]`.

Comment: if (gvDetails.PageIndex == 0)      {       var lastRow = gvDetails.Rows[0];} // Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. You will get the first row of the first page.

Comment: can you pls take a look at my updated post on adding new datarow at the first row of the grid.

Comment: Try `dtDetails.Rows.Insert` method, using which you can insert a row at any valid position. And bind the `dtDetails` later

Comment: I can see InserAt method but couldn't frame it properly to the statement.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat(v=vs.110).aspx And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942208/how-to-insert-row-at-any-desired-position-in-datatable

Comment: I updated my post. Initially when page loads I am not able to see that first row. But when got to second page and come back to first page I can see that first row added. Pls correct me if I am wrong. Really appreciate your help by far.

Comment: Need to add the same code in `PageIndexChanging` event.

Comment: Yes I added the same code for both page load and page indexing event as updated in my post.

Comment: Yes I added the code after binding the grid but still the new row doesn't show up on page load.

Comment: Check the `gvDetails.PageIndex` for first page when you navigate back to first page by placing a `BreakPoint` in the `PageIndexChanging` even and set that value in the `if` condition.

Comment: Initially when page loads the pageindex is 0 and when page indexing is done the page index value is 1.

Comment: What is the `PageIndex` when you click on `Page 1`? Find that `PageIndex` and use it in `PageIndexChanging` event.

Comment: When I click onpage 1 the ``PageIndex`` is 0.

Comment: So it should go into the `if` block then. And hide the buttons, for first page.

Comment: Yes the problem the row is not coming initially on page load. But appears on page indexing.

Comment: Check the `PageIndex` in `Page_Load`. It should appear in `Page_Load` too.

Comment: The ``PageIndex`` in page load is too 0.Also I have given same page index in page load and page index.

Comment: Then it should work correctly. Try casting the `Buttons` like `(lastRow.FindControl("btnEdit") as Button)`, then set `Visible = false`.

Comment: Yes I tried and is the same. I don't think its because of visibility since the row doesn't appear on pageload.

Comment: Row will be available as soon as data is bounded to the gridview(if there is data exists in the datasource).

Comment: Yes as soon as the grid is binded we are adding the new row to it correct. So it should appear. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You need to add new row to the datasource (in your case its DataTable) and then bind it to the grid.(Thats what happening in your give sample code).

Comment: Updated my post. Pls take a look.

Comment: I saw `gvODetails` in `PageIndexChanging` event.

Comment: But still its the same.

Comment: Yes its entering into if block.